# Using も when subject is different

Tags: particle-も

The particle も is usually explained as similar to *also*. However, examples also always leans towards *too*, and always in the context of the sentence's subject (and always referring to the same subject).

*Me too*

*I like cats too*

However, I've always wondered if it was valid to use it almost like an interjection, to change the topic:

> A: 今日の授業を欠席しました I didn't attend today's class
>
> A: 月曜日の宿題*も*忘れました I've *also* forgotten last monday's homework

So when the subject is different, can you still use this particle?

Comment: Funny cuz in my native language (portuguese), both "also" and "too" are the same word. I think you cannot use も the way you intend,  this "also" you're using is like "in addition..." right? I think も needs either tha same subject or the "action" in the sentence must be in the same context

Comment: Eg: John - 日本語は難しいね(japanese is hard, right?). Tomya - そうだね、でも、英語も難しいよ(that's right, but english is hard too). Diffferent subjects but you can still use も! One question,  "english is also hard" is this ungrammatical in english?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use も that way.

> 今日は学校に遅刻しました。宿題**も**忘れました。

> あの選手は守備がいい。その上、足**も**速い。

> ブサイクな女は、性格**も**悪い。

> あさっての夕方ごろからくずれるそうです。気温**も**下がるそうです。海や山**も**あれるそうです。 (quoted from [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38688/9831))

Comment: この本（[日本語能力試験N2文法スターターズブック](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=SqWUar94xf4C&pg=RA1-PA12&lpg=RA1-PA12&dq=%E9%81%85%E5%88%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F+%E5%AE%BF%E9%A1%8C%E3%82%82&source=bl&ots=e1rFFu3wy5&sig=HiBQ05m64V6HrvR8Ox5_8Hwz_BA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi17aPBy9bTAhVFyLwKHXdnDUwQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%E9%81%85%E5%88%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%20%E5%AE%BF%E9%A1%8C%E3%82%82&f=false)）の例文がちょっと似てるかも：「今朝は遅刻したうえ、宿題**も**忘れて、先生に怒られた。」「彼は頭がいいうえに、スポーツ**も**得意だ。」

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. I've sort of thought the same thing, and have used it in that way, but am not positive that it's correct. I think if you show that the *other thing* you're attaching も to is the verb then it would be alright. As in, I *did this* and *also did* this. "I didn't attend class. And also (an other thing I did was) forgot the homework".

So in Japanese maybe something like

```
今日の授業を欠席しました。
月曜日の宿題を忘れたこともしました。
```

You just have to nominalize the verb then use も as normal. I think you noticed that what sounds odd about 宿題も忘れた is that it sounds like you're saying you forgot your homework and also forgot something else.